# Will Intel Atom Processor laptops support cloned a Arduino with CH340 driver?

Tags: arduino-ide

I am planning to buy a low cost and low weight laptop with an Atom Processor.

I only have cloned Arduinos - will the Arduino drivers and IDE work on laptops which come with Atom Processors?

Comment: Are you wondering if you could install the Arduino IDE on the laptop?

Comment: Yes. Original FTDI chip will work but I am having cloned Arduino with CH340 and i am using Intel I3 which is working fine. Also planning to buy Atom processor based low cost laptop (Z3735F variant). Whether the driver will support the cloned one.

Comment: Install the needed drivers and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

The processor in your laptop is irrelevant. It is the operating system you should be thinking about, not the processor.

If the operating system has drivers for the CH340 chip, and Windows does, as you already know since you are using it already, then you already know that the answer is a big fat yes.

The only time you need to worry about if the processor will support something is when you are switching to a completely different archetecture such as ARM.

Comment: Thanks. I am planning to buy  http://www.snapdeal.com/product/micromax-canvas-l1161-lapbook-intel/661756382388 which is comes with windows 10